# java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :-1.0 Actual :<12.0>

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new for Junit and Mockito and i am trying to test below code but ia m getting exception

java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :-1.0
Actual   :<12.0>

```
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.zycsolego.Prism.PrismTest.volumeTest01(PrismTest.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Triangle.java

```
package com.zycsolego.Prism;

public interface Triangle {
    double area(int s1, int s2, int s3) throws Exception;
}
```

Prism.java

```
package com.zycsolego.Prism;

public class Prism {
    private int s1, s2, s3, height;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Prism() {}
    public Prism(int s1, int s2, int s3, int height) {
        setPrism(s1, s2, s3, height);
    }

    public void setPrism(int s1, int s2, int s3, int height) {
        this.s1 = s1; this.s2 = s2; this.s3 = s3;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }

    public double volume() {
        try {
            double area = triangle.area(s1, s2, s3);
            double volume = area * height;
            return volume;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1.0;
        }
    }

}
```

PrismTest.java

```
package com.zycsolego.Prism;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PrismTest {
    private Prism prism;
    private Triangle triangle;

    @Test
    public void volumeTest01() throws Exception {
        int s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, height = 2;
        prism = new Prism(s1, s2, s3, height);
        triangle = mock(Triangle.class);

        when(triangle.area(s1, s2, s3)).thenReturn(6.0);

        double v = prism.volume();
        assertEquals(v, equalTo(-1.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void volumeTest02() throws Exception {

        int s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, height = 2;
        prism = new Prism(s1, s2, s3, height);
        triangle = mock(Triangle.class);

        when(triangle.area(s1, s2, s3)).thenThrow(new Exception());

        double v = prism.volume();
        assertEquals(v, lt(0.0));
    }
}
```

then I get the following errors. Please help me find and fix the bug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxoA4.png)

Comment: You have to inject your mocked triangle object in the prism. Add a constructor argument in prism which accepts triangle and pass it with this call prism = new Prism(s1, s2, s3, height);.

Comment: Thank you ver much !

Comment: 1. Get your assertions right (tip: check javadoc for assertEquals) 2. Do you really need to mock triangle area calculation? It is a simple method, I see indirection via field and interface as over-engineering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For `volumeTest01()`

In your test, you are comparing the result of prism's volumes to -1.

```
    double v = prism.volume();
    assertEquals(v, equalTo(-1.0));
```

Volume is calculated as `height x triangle.area.`

The statement
`when(triangle.area(s1, s2, s3)).thenReturn(6.0);`
tells the test engine to return `6.0` as result when computation of `triangle.area()` is performed on the triangle Mock.

So, you end up having `v = 6.0 x 2 = 12.0` , and the assertEquals is actually comparing 12 being equal to -1.

```
   ` assertEquals(v, equalTo(-1.0)); `
```

To have the test pass, you can have instead
`assertEquals(v, equalTo(12.0));`.

Depending on what you want to test, you could change the values of assertEquals method.